# How to add Pixlee Social Feed to a React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, instagram

I have created a social feed for my Instagram using Pixlee and got a sample to use with my page looking like this:

```js
<div id="pixlee_container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">window.PixleeAsyncInit = function() {Pixlee.init({apiKey:'ThisIsASecretApiKey'});Pixlee.addSimpleWidget({widgetId:'32861'});};</script>
<script src="//instafeed.assets.pxlecdn.com/assets/pixlee_widget_1_0_0.js"></script>
```

How can I incorporate this into a react page? How can I load and execute whats within the script tags in a React context?

EDIT:
I found that I can use `<Helmet>` to include scripts within a React component like this:

```js
<Helmet>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.PixleeAsyncInit = function() {Pixlee.init({apiKey:'ThisIsASecretApiKey'});Pixlee.addSimpleWidget({widgetId:'32861'});};</script>
  <script src="//instafeed.assets.pxlecdn.com/assets/pixlee_widget_1_0_0.js"></script>
</Helmet>
```

Doing this I get an error for the first script tag saying:
`C:\utveckling\blog\src\pages\instagram.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "}" (18:122)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by putting the script parts within a `useEffect` tag like this:

```
const InstagramFeed = (): JSX.Element => {

  // Init Pixlee Social Feed
  useEffect(() => {
    window.PixleeAsyncInit = function() {
      Pixlee.init({ apiKey: "ThisIsASecretApiKey" })
      Pixlee.addSimpleWidget({ widgetId: "32861" })
    }

    const scriptTag = document.createElement("script")
    scriptTag.src =
      "//instafeed.assets.pxlecdn.com/assets/pixlee_widget_1_0_0.js"
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <div id="pixlee_container" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add the scripts to your `index.html` that is in your public folder and your `div` whatever component you want. See this CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-tdd-3x6pn?file=/public/index.html:587-606

If you set your key in the script function, it should work.

Comment: If I edit the file in the public folder I would have to redo it after every build, or am i missing something here? :)

Comment: No, file `public/index.html` is not overriden at each build, but copied to `build` folder

Comment: I'm using Gatsby with React, so might be something different because of that. The `Public` folder is the delivery for me, I don´t have any `build` folder. Did not think that mattered, so did not mention it in the question.

Comment: You can add the script tags anywhere, inside you main component etc.